# How can I find feed or XML of a particular news source

Tags: rss, html-content-extraction

I want to get xml file of a particular news source, Of if there is any project which converts html news to xml, parsing page and tokenizing its various traits such as date, author name, title, content etc. in a single xml or similar type of file. 
For example see this link:
http://daily.bhaskar.com/article/NAT-TOP-yeddyurappa-breaks-venkaiah-naidus-laptop-slaps-minister-reports-2318460.html 
How can I extract content, author, date etc from this webpage. Or if I can find this webpage's feed I can do that easily. But How can I search for that.

Answer (score 0):

which technology are you using ?

If it's a purely client-side / web solution then you'll find js options [in a previous StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226663/parse-rss-with-jquery). If you're on the server-side you can [use WebClient/LINQ to hit the ATOM feed and parse it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290851/linq-with-atom-feeds)

Answer (score 0):

To find out if a page has a feed scan the HTML for a specific <link> tag with these **rel** and **type** attributes:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Page as RSS"
 href="http://example.com/page/feed">
```

The feed URL is stored in the **href** attribute. This mechanism is called [RSS Autodiscovery](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-autodiscovery)